# Dynamic UI Progress Updates using Interface + ExecutorService Issue

Tags: java, android, executorservice

So I have a music application. I am trying to update the UI with the progress of the media player (like current time, current song, album cover) everytime the song changes. I found that using interfaces was a awesome magical way of communication between activity and fragments so I implemented an interface in my MusicManger class. My code will show what and how did it.

**Two problems**

1) Commented look below, ExecutorService seems to stop after one loop. No Errors in catch block (this is why I tagged with java)

2) Commented please look, All the System.out methods print but the UI doesn't update. I do believe I called the method from mainThread so it should update.

I'll show code in logical order will add titles in bold before code segment to tell you basic idea of code.

**Passing UI references from fragment to MusicManager class, code below in Fragment class**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_songlist, container, false);

    // Set the adapter

    TextView musicManagerSongName, musicManagerCurrent, musicManagerTotal;
    ProgressBar musicManagerProgress;
    ImageView musicManagerImageView;
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(R.id.slist);
    musicManagerSongName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    musicManagerCurrent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    musicManagerTotal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    musicManagerProgress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    musicManagerImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.passUIReferences(musicManagerSongName, musicManagerCurrent, musicManagerTotal, musicManagerProgress, musicManagerImageView, view);

// line above is a method within MusicManager that takes the references will show code next!

    ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.playbuttonbar);
    ImageButton nextButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.nextbuttonbar);
    ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.backbuttonbar);
    ImageButton toggleButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.shufflebuttonbar);
    ImageButton pausebutton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.pausebuttonbar);
    playbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonbar);
    playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer.stateChange(1);
            }catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });
    backButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backbutton1);
    nextButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nextbutton1);
    toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shufflebuttonselected);
    pausebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebutton1);
    pausebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer.stateChange(0);
            } catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    });
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ((MainActivity) mListener).restoreActionBar();

    return view;
}
```

**As Commended above the code that is located in MusicManager class that takes references and stores them. Also shows interface implementation with MusicManager class. And the Executor service**

```
public void passUIReferences(View... views) {
    this.uiElements = views;
}

 private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private MediaplayerUpdateInterface uiUpdateInterface;

public MediaPlayerManager(MediaplayerUpdateInterface inter) {
    this.player = new MediaPlayer();
    this.uiUpdateInterface = inter;

// The below line starts the single thread while loop for excutorservice and only loops and prints "this" once after I start one song then it never loops again
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if (player.isPlaying() && uiElements != null) {
                    System.out.println("this");
                    uiUpdateInterface.updateUI(uiElements, 0);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public interface MediaplayerUpdateInterface {
    public void updateUI(View[] views, int type);
}
```

**Finally some code from MainActivity class that actually is suppose to update the UI** note that both println's work as expected but only once as stated above because of the executorservice issue

```
  public static MediaPlayerManager mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayerManager(new MediaPlayerManager.MediaplayerUpdateInterface() {
    @Override
    public void updateUI(View[] views, int type) {
        System.out.println("check1 " + type);
        updateMediaplayerViews(views, type);
    }
});

private static void updateMediaplayerViews(View[] views, int type)
{
    switch(type) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("that?");
            ((TextView)views[0]).setText(mediaPlayer.getCurrentSongInfo().getName().length() > 22? mediaPlayer.getCurrentSongInfo().getName().substring(0, 19)+"..." : mediaPlayer.getCurrentSongInfo().getName());
            break;
    }
    views[views.length - 1].invalidate();
}
```

The view array is shown perviously! Also the last view in the array is shown as the main view for songlist fragment.

I am sorry for all the code I've tried to debug it as you can see from my println's there is just something I am unaware of going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there was an error that I needed to catch to see within the following code:

```
private static void updateMediaplayerViews(View[] views, int type)
{
switch(type) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("that?");
        ((TextView)views[0]).setText(mediaPlayer.getCurrentSongInfo().getName().length() > 22? mediaPlayer.getCurrentSongInfo().getName().substring(0, 19)+"..." : mediaPlayer.getCurrentSongInfo().getName());
        break;
}
views[views.length - 1].invalidate();
}
```

The issue is I was trying to change the view from a different thread then the one which created it. Solving it was pretty long and painful but basically I made it nonstactic used more interfaces then used the famous

Mainactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(....));